# Google pubsub golang subscriber stops receiving new published message(s) after being idle for a few hours

Tags: go, google-cloud-pubsub, subscriber

I created a TOPIC in google pubsub, and created a SUBSCRIPTION inside the TOPIC, with the following settings

[image]

then I wrote a [puller in go](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/pubsub), using its [Receive](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/pubsub#hdr-Receiving) to pull and acknowledge published messages

```
package main

import (
    ...
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()

    client, err := pubsub.NewClient(ctx, config.C.Project)
    if err != nil {
       // do things with err
    }
    sub := client.Subscription(config.C.PubsubSubscription)
    err := sub.Receive(ctx, func(ctx context.Context, msg *pubsub.Message) {
        msg.Ack()
    })

    if err != context.Canceled {
      logger.Error(fmt.Sprintf("Cancelled: %s", err.Error()))
    }
    if err != nil {
      logger.Error(fmt.Sprintf("Error: %s", err.Error()))
    }
  }
```

Nothing fancy, its working well, but then after a while (~ after 3 hours idle), it stops receiving new published messages, no error(s), nothing. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, there can be several reasons why a subscriber may stop receiving messages:

1. If a subscriber does not ack or nack messages, the flow control limits can be reached, meaning no more messages can be delivered. This does not seem to be the case in your particular instance given that you immediately ack messages.
2. If another subscriber starts up for the same subscription, it could be receiving the messages. In this scenario, one would expect the subscriber to receive a subset of the messages rather than no messages at all.
3. Publishers just stop publishing messages and therefore there are no messages to receive. If you restart the subscriber and it starts receiving messages again, this probably isn't the case. You can also verify that a backlog is being built up by looking at the [Stackdriver metric](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-pubsub) for `subscription/backlog_bytes`.

If your problem does not fall into one of those categories, it would be best to reach out to Google Cloud support with your project name, topic name, and subscription name so that they can narrow down the issue to either your user code, the client library itself, or the service.

Comment: If my flow control limit is reached - how can I know about that? I suspect that some of my messages have been working too long.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing something similar and I was pretty sure there was not another subscriber pulling those messages.

Try this: go to the topic, create a new bogus subscription (name it whatever you want, because you'll just delete it later). Right after I did that both the fake subscription (which I was using the [python sample code client](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/pubsub/cloud-client) to subscribe to) and the real one was receiving messages again. Strange solution, but maybe it kicked the topic awake again.

Hopefully someone from Google could give us some insight into what's happening here, but I'm definitely not paying them enough to get direct support.

Answer (score 0):

Few changes will help you to investigate the issue better:
- Check error from Receive
- Use separate context for Receive

```
ctx := context.Background()
err := sub.Receive(ctx, func(ctx context.Context, msg *pubsub.Message) {
    msg.Ack()
})
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: did that [i updated mny question], it doesn't show any error, i also use `GRPC_GO_LOG_SEVERITY_LEVEL=info` just so that it logs everything else

Answer (score 0):

Does your code work before? I have problems with PubSub since today. Methods like `get_topic()`, `create_topic()` in Python PubSub library stop working, but I don't have any problems with sending and pulling messages. Yesterday everything was working fine but today not...

Comment: the code just works, but it stops pulling or receiving message(s) after a while without throwing any error(s). My team is currently trying out the python lib as an alternative, will update you